# Re-write userprofile URL (remove.html)

Tags: mod-rewrite

Any Ideas how to change remove .html in this mod-rewrite script
Doesnt work if I remove ".html"

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /userprofile.php?member_id=$1 [L]
```

Works as

```
http://site.com/12.html
```

but wants to have it as

```
http://site.com/12
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MODIFIED:
I have tested the following and they work on a CentOS server running Apache.

For directory rewriting:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ http://www.google.com [L,R]
```

That will redirect http://www.site.com/test to http://www.google.com.

For all files in a directory this will work:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/([^/]*)(.*)$ http://www.google.com [L,R]
```

That will redirect www.site.com/test/12.html or www.site.com/test/298.aspx or any other file in the "test" directory to www.google.com.

So this may be more what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^/12/([^/]*)(.*)$ /userprofile.php?member_id=$1 [L,R]
```

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ /userprofile.php?member_id=$1 [L]
```

That is if you are trying to do the rewrite for files...

It will be slightly different if you want to do the rewrite against a directory.

Comment: Are you trying to do the rewrite against a page named "12" with any file type, or are you doing it against a directory named "12"?

Comment: if you look at the code you will see that it works already. Just to remove the .html extension.

Answer (score 1):

To make the `.html` optional, put it in a group and use the `?` quantifier:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(\.html)?$ /userprofile.php?member_id=$1 [L]
```

But as this pattern will now also match any single path segment, you should make it more specific to only match your specific URL path pattern. In this case `\d+` instead of `[^/]*` would be a better choice:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)(\.html)?$ /userprofile.php?member_id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the backslash as well ("\.html").

Comment: Try `^([^/]+)$` (+ instead of *) so it won't match an empty path.